# Filter output of a SyliusResourceBundle API call reponse

Tags: symfony, sylius, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using the SyliusResourceBundle as a standalone package for exposing data through an API.

When i request entities that have relationships with some other entities, i always get a full response with all the related entities properties included. This leads to heavy JSON responses, and too much data to download on the client side.

Typically, if my entity has a $user property like this :

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="object")
 */
private $user;
```

I get all the user's stuff in the API response when i request the object : name, email, etc.

Is there a way to only get a list of properties/entities i need ? Like with an annotation or something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, SyliusResourceBundle uses JMSSeriliazerBundle, so it was just a matter of exclusion policy in the Resource Entity.

I just had to exclude all fields at the Entity level, and only expose the field i needed like this :

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
use Sylius\Component\Resource\Model\ResourceInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* 
*  @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class MyResource implements ResourceInterface
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="object")
    */
    private $user;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    * @JMS\Expose()
    */
    private $name;
}
```

See doc [here](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies).